# Get root taxonomy name in drupal view

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm using Drupal 6 and have a view with a field having the taxonomy name.

But I want to get the root taxonomy name. How can I have this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to get the vocabulary name or the name of the parent of the specified term?

Comment: I want the root name and the parent isn't helpful because I have a two level depth taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I haven't found a way to do this purely through the Views administration, but you could create a template file for a Views field to do this. It sounds like you want to replace the term name with the root name...

If you could make that field have the taxonomy term id (tid) instead of the name, you can create a template for the field (determine the name for the tpl file under *Basic Settings->Theme*) and add this code:

```
<?php
  $term_parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($output);
  print $term_parents[count($term_parents) - 1]->name;
?>
```

This will replace the term id and instead will display the root term name in its place.

If you are stuck on using the name, you could always throw a database query in there to convert the name to the term id to use with the template code.

Comment: Awesome man! Great work! But :( it's almost done...I have the tid as "Exclude from display" and in the next field I'm "rewriting the output of the field"...unfornately it shows the tid and not the name...I know that he goes through the template file because a die in there crashes the website :) Can you help once again? Thanks.

Comment: @foxtrot ok, how are you rewriting the other field? Can you post what you entered in the rewrite box?